# Calculate the average of a variable by percentile

Tags: stata

I have the percentiles of profits of multiple firms and the costs of each firm. I want to calculate the average of the costs of the firms in each percentile group so that I can graph the average costs vs percentiles of profits.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have a variable `percentile_group` that identifies the group, right? and some other variable `cost`. then you just need to run

```
collapse cost, by(percentile_group)
```